cPanel files to VScode with FTP connection - search into files not working
I have took my cPanel files with FTP connection to VScode. All files are correctly loaded in and can be live added.
But there is an issue. When using CTRL + SHIFT + F or the search in VScode it doesn't search into the FTP file what is open in VScode.
Only when I open 1 file I do can search into this file.
I have many many files and I search for specific codes into these files to go quicker. But it doesn't work because I can't search directly in all files.

Anyone has a solution?
Thanks!

This is basically a limitation of the ftp protocol.  Not much you can do, except start working and developing on your local machine (and just push your code to the server when it's actually ready)

Thanks! Sad there is no solution on this because it would be very useful. Anyway it makes sense. I’ll take it with me.
